# Source Link When Someone Copies Text

Tags: javascript

I'm very much a newbie i found code to add Source Link When Someone Copies Text
but my link like that

```
https://example.com/post/341296/blabla2022
```

I just need

```
https://example.com/post/341296
```

can you help me ?

```
function addLink() {
    //Get the selected text and append the extra info
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    pagelink = ". Read more at: " + document.location.href;
    copytext = selection + pagelink;
    //Create a new div to hold the prepared text
    newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    //hide the newly created container
    newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
    newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';

    //insert the container, fill it with the extended text, and define the new selection
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);
    newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
    selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(newdiv);
    }, 100);
}
document.addEventListener('copy', addLink);
```

Comment: I would: Get `window.location.pathname`, use regex/some string manipulation to extract the post ID, use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to reconstruct the new URL in your output string (`\`Read more at: https://example.com/post/${id}\``)

Comment: i need edit my code to remove "/blabla2022 or any text Like example"

Comment: If you use `window.location.pathname`, you will get `/post/341296/blabla2022`, what have you tried so far to extract the desired part? One easy example would be: look into using `.split()` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) based on the `/` and then get the relevant array element)